# jsTree - cannot create new node - all other functions work well

Tags: jstree

Deselect and hover funcntions work fina but create/delete/rename don't.

What do is do wrong?

info.json contains 5 nodes marked from 1 to 5.

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jstree\dist\themes\default\style.min.css" />
<script src="jstree\dist\jstree.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

$('#test_tree').jstree({
'core' : {
  'data' : {
    'url' : 'info.json',
    'data' : function (node) {
      return { 'id' : node.id };
    }
  }
  }
});
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container" >

  <div id="nav_bar">
    <button id="create" onclick = "demo_create()">Create</button>
  </div> 
  <div id="test_tree"></div
</div>  

<script>
            function demo_create() {
$.jstree.reference('#test_tree').hover_node('ajson5');
$.jstree.reference('#test_tree').deselect_node('ajson1');
$.jstree.reference('#test_tree').create_node();
            };

</script>

</body>
```

I used same example from official site but it doesn't work
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12):

First, in order for changes to be made to the tree, checkcallback in core config need to be set to true.

```
$('#test_tree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : {
        'url' : 'info.json',
        'data' : function (node) {
            return { 'id' : node.id };
        },
        check_callback : true
    }
}
```

You need to at least pass the parent.id to the create_node function.

```
$.jstree.reference('#test_tree').create_node('ajson1');
```

You could check the API at [the jstree website](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=create_node&f=create_node%28%5Bobj,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded%5D%29) for the full parameter list.

Comment: No, it didn't help. I used all way to create node, but nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the configuration.

Comment: Still the same, no errors in console, hover/select works fine but "create" doesn't

Comment: This code doesn't work with the latest jstree because checkcallback needs to be check_callback.

Comment: Remember guys this is javascript. You can debug it to track down the error. This post fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I have been trying to create nodes to no avail all because of the lack of `check_callback` flag.  Thank you so much @Troy.

Answer (score 2):

Demo jsTreeView 3.2.1 version

```
 $("#treeView").jstree({ 'core': {
                'check_callback': true,
                'themes': {
                    "variant": "large"
                },
                'data':
               [{"id":"1","parent":"#","text":"Parent Node"}]
                }
            });
```

You are missing the single quotation mark for the check_callback, after using that it will work. e.g. `'check_callback': true`.

Code to create new Node

```
var ref_treeview = $("#treeView").jstree(true);
sel = ref_treeview.get_selected();
if (!sel.length) {
    return false;
}
sel = sel[0];
sel = ref_treeview.create_node(sel, "childNode", "last", CreateNode,true);
```

Here CreateNode is my Callback function name

Answer (score 1):

you have to send the selected element.
use the following (this is basically the code of the create button in the demo page http://www.jstree.com/demo/):

```
var tree = $("#test_tree").jstree(true);
var sel = tree.get_selected();
if (!sel.length) 
{
    return false;
}
sel = sel[0];
sel = tree.create_node(sel);
if (sel) 
{
  tree.edit(sel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time when you create the jstree instance you just need to configure the 
'core' setting as shown bellow:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        'core':{check_callback : true}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the type of the newly created node like so:

```
$('#tree').jstree().create_node('#', {'id': 'blah', 'text': 'new node', 'type': 'folder'}, 'last', function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

jstree documentation should be improved.

Answer (score 0):

using code from the other answers, I was able to make the following work:
*Please note, this actually works. I am using it to create menus for an external ajax API.*

```
function makeNode(menunode, menuname){
    var inst = $.jstree.reference("#treemenu"); //get menu instance
    var obj = inst.get_node(menunode);
    inst.create_node(obj, menuname); //creates nodes. use "#" to make root nodes
    inst.open_node(obj); // open the node (unfold)
});
```

usage:

```
//create menu instance and allow tree changes
$('#treemenu').jstree({'core' : {'check_callback': true}});

makeNode("#", "main menu"); //makes root node
makeNode("#j1_1", "submenu in main menu"); //makes sub node
```

this is assuming that you have a div with `id="treemenu"` thusly

```
<div id="treemenu"></div>
```